# How to combine 2 images with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 images which I'd like to place one on top of the other. I made this line:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\image_1.jpg" -i "C:\image_2.jpg" -q:v 1 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=800:-1[v0];[v0][1:v]vstack" C:\combined.jpg
```

and it works when they have the same resolution 800x800 and when the resolution of the first one is smaller than `image_2`.

Is it possible to add some mathematics instead of 800 to make this line suitable for any type of resolutions when the first one is bigger or the second is bigger (width and height separately)?

I want to find a maximal dimension and scale another image to it preserving aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio of 2 images is not the same fill the holes with plain white (255,255,255).

I suppose the mathematics should be like this:

```
w1, h1 - width and height of the 1st img
w2, h2 - width and height of the 2st img
w1', h1', w2', h2' - width and height of resulted images

if w1 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w2/h2>=1 -> w2'=w1; h2'=h2*w2'/w2
if w1 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w2/h2<1  -> h2'=w1; w2'=w2*h2'/h2

if h1 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w2/h2>=1 -> w2'=h1; h2'=h2*w2'/w2
if h1 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w2/h2<1  -> h2'=h1; w2'=w2*h2'/h2

if w2 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w1/h1>=1 -> w1'=w2; h1'=h1*w1'/w1
if w2 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w1/h1<1  -> h1'=w2; w1'=w1*h1'/h1

if h2 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w1/h1>=1 -> w1'=h2; h1'=h1*w1'/w1
if h2 max{w1, h1, w2, h2} -> if w1/h1<1  -> h1'=h2; w1'=w1*h1'/h1
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXoWF.png) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gOTH.png)

If the two images i1 and i2 are 800x800 and - 436x800 resp:
the combined image will be 800x1600.

If the two images i1 and i2 are 300x400 and 200x500 resp:
max(300,400,200,500)=500; 300x400 -> (300*500/400=375)x500 ; 200x500 -> 200x500. Align the smallest one (200x500) to center, fill the gaps (2 gaps: (375-200)/2=88) with white (255,255,255).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i image_0.jpg -i image_1.jpg -filter_complex
       "sws_flags=bicubic;
        color=c=white:4x4,format=yuvj444p,trim=end_frame=1,split=2[c0][c1];
        [0][1]scale2ref='if(gte(max(main_w,main_h),max(iw,ih)),main_w,if(gte(main_w,main_h),iw,oh*mdar))':
                        'if(gte(max(main_w,main_h),max(iw,ih)),main_h,if(gte(main_w,main_h),ow/mdar,ih))'[0max][1ref];
        [1ref][0max]scale2ref='if(gte(max(main_w,main_h),max(iw,ih)),main_w,if(gte(main_w,main_h),iw,oh*mdar))':
                        'if(gte(max(main_w,main_h),max(iw,ih)),main_h,if(gte(main_w,main_h),ow/mdar,ih))'[1max][0max];
        [c0][0max]scale2ref[c0max][0max];[c1][1max]scale2ref[c1max][1max];[c0max][c1max]scale2ref='if(gte(main_w,iw),main_w,iw)':main_h[c0max][c1max];
        [c1max][c0max]scale2ref='if(gte(main_w,iw),main_w,iw)':main_h[c1max][c0max];
        [c0max][0max]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[0f];[c1max][1max]overlay=format=auto:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[1f];
        [0f][1f]vstack,setsar=1"  out.jpg
```

This will scale the image with the smaller dimensions proportionally to match the largest dimension of both the inputs. Then the resized images are overlaid on a canvas of the same width and finally stacked.

---

**Old answer**

You'll need to use the [scale2ref](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter, twice.

```
ffmpeg -i image1 -i image2 -filter_complex
       "[0][1]scale2ref=w='max(iw,main_w)':h=ow/mdar[0max][1ref];
        [1ref][0max]scale2ref=w='max(iw,main_w)':h=ow/mdar[1max][0max];
        [0max][1max]vstack" -q:v 1 combined.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. I created a bat file with these 4 lines, replaced image1, image2 and combined.jpg with full path. And nothing happens.

Comment: It's a single line, separated here for legibility.

Comment: Thank you! But it still does not work the way I wrote above. When image1 has resolution 800x800, image2 - 436x800 the combined image will be 800x2267 instead of 800x1236. Because h2 is already hitting max value of w1 or h1. Image2 was scaled up, but it should not. All resulted images separately must not exceed max value of original {w1, h1, w2, h2}.

Comment: The combined image can't have height 1236. The native heights are 800 for both images, so unless a downscale is allowed, min height of result will be 1600.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: When image1 has resolution 800x800, image2 - 436x800 the combined image will be 800x2267 instead of 800x1600. I placed Example image in the original post.

Comment: Gyan, your code does not evaluate the height of the images. If w/h<1 the code must change height to max(w1,h1,w2,h2). See examples in the post.

Comment: If the two images i1 and i2 are 300x400 and 200x500 resp, what should be the sizes after scaling, and then after padding?

Comment: Thank you for your help). max(300,400,200,500)=500; 300x400 -> (300*500/400=375)x500 ; 200x500 -> 200x500. Align the smallest one (200x500) to center, fill the gaps (2 gaps: (375-200)/2=88) with white (255,255,255).

Comment: Combined image size: 375x1000.

Comment: Gyan, Is it possible to do with ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, but it's tedious. Give me some time.

Comment: Generic method added

Comment: What is Generic method?

Comment: What you requested

Comment: Thank you very much! It's amazing! I thought you won't come back. Could you explain a few things: Why do we need this "trim=end_frame=1" and what does it mean (didn't find it in documentation)? And why do I see bilinear in the report?